# Having issues with triggring alarm in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a notification when an alarm triggers.But alarm is not triggering and also no notification is displaying. Here is Here is the MainActivity.java file -

```
package com.kaushal28.kaushal1

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scheduleAlarm();
    }

public void scheduleAlarm()
{

    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10000;
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
     Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And here is the AlarmReciever Class -

```
package com.kaushal28.kaushal1;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{ 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1)
    {

        System.out.println("Notification setup");
        Uri sound =      RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent       pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,1,intent,0);

        Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentText("TESTING NOTIFIACTION")
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                .setSound(sound)
                .build();
NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)  ;
notificationManager.notify(1,notification);




    }
}
```

And here is my `menifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kaushal28.kaushal1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses- permission>
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"></receiver>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

What I'm missing here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your receiver in the manifest file? Also, please fix your indenting :)

Comment: see my menifest file @LaurIvan

Comment: Yep, you need to [add your receiver](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) in the manifest file. otherwise, your app won't "see" it and the intent will just be discarded.

Comment: How can i add receiver?

Comment: the receiver must be in the `<application>` tag, not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver is missing from the manifest file you need to add it according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

For brevity, I paraphrase the relevant bits:

> Add the receiver to your app's manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"
        android:enabled="false">
</receiver>
```